# How to turn off "Suggested: ..." video pop-ups in the YouTube android app?

Tags: youtube

I don't know if this is something new or I've only just started to notice it but very often a few seconds into most YouTube videos viewed on the app I'm finding an annoying white box with a letter "i" in a circle pops up, promoting some other video. It's possible to swipe it away, but that is also distracting and several times I've been hit by more than one of these in the same video.

Is there any way to turn this off?

I've looked through the app settings but couldn't find anything. I've already got all YouTube notifications turned off, and it seems to be unrelated to the "info" that some video creators add.

Here's an example of what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These are Youtube cards (also known as Info Cards or Interactive Cards as described here: [All about cards on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Sex3r_CNWU&feature=youtu.be) and here: [How To Setup and Use Youtube Info / Interactive Cards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUMNmfQqnSA).

There are inserted into the videos by owners to (for marketing, advertising or information etc)  the viewer.

As described on the support page:

> You can choose which apps and websites show cards in your feed, and
>   you can turn off cards from apps and websites at any time. You can
>   also get more personalized cards by letting Google learn which apps
>   and websites you use most.

**The fix: Turning off cards from apps & websites**

On your Android phone or tablet:

- Open the Google app Google Search.
- At the top left, tap Menu Menu → Customize → Apps & websites → Receive Now cards from apps and websites? → No.

Sources

1. [Add cards to videos](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6140493?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)
2. [See or remove cards from apps & websites](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6101479?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)

Note: For other ads not related related to info cards you need to use an ad blocker or patch host file to prevent ads, **this fix is only for info cards and not ads**.

Comment: This sounds promising (albeit staggeringly unintuitive... thanks Google), except my "Customize" button is greyed out and I can't figure out why. Any ideas? All I can find online is this https://support.google.com/websearch/forum/AAAAgtjJeM4B6ucu70bIIY/?hl=en

Comment: I guess this now has to do with language settings (you might neeed to set default language to English - US, as suggested in forums) Alternatively unistalling and reinstalling the app may do the trick. Good luck!

Comment: I don't have an app on my phone called "Google Search", and I don't want to install it just to remove cards from Youtube.  Surely there must be a way from within the Youtube app to do it?